# DIV won't stack in IE

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a WordPress installation using Genesis - Metric as a theme with custom CSS. I've added two widgets to the Header Right area and they are displaying side-by-side in IE (which is the browser for 86% of the site's users) and stacked in Chrome and Firefox. I want them to stack (display on top of one another) in IE. I've tried changing the float, positioning, width etc. but with no luck.

FYI
- one widget is a custom menu while the other is Text.
- you can see a sample at http://www.saveda.com/sandbox

Any thoughts?

Comment: I do not see any stacked widgets in Chrome or IE. I see three widgets in the center side-by-side and four widgets in the footer side-by-side. If I navigate to a sub-page I see a single widget in the right hand sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Change the width for `#header .widget-area` at line 122 to `256px`.

Alternatively you could add `#text-3 { clear:right }`.